# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 reuse previous frame

Tags: android, opengl-es, framebuffer

I am looking for a minimal example where each frame will reuse the triangles from the previous frame. I have been trying over and over unsuccessfully, so I do not have any code worth showing, although I do have a program that works by drawing to the default framebuffer.

During on draw I would add new triangles to a framebuffer object, and the frame would be copied to the default framebuffer. Since I would not clear the frame buffer object, it would retain its rgba values and depths, so that when I add more triangles the next frame, the previous ones would still remain. (Later I will reduce the alpha value of the triangles from previous frames to produce a fade effect, but for simplicity sake reuse the previous triangles exactly as they are is fine.)

I am finding it very difficult to understand how the frame buffer object works, and whether or not I need to create render, depth, and texture buffers. I suspect that I need render and depth buffers since I would like to retain that information between draws but do not need the texture buffer.

I thought the onDrawFrame method would look something like this:

1. New data is added to the framebuffer object.
2. The default framebuffer is cleared.
3. The information from the framebuffer object is copied to the default framebuffer and then the default framebuffer is rendered.

I believe I am doing steps 1 and 2 correctly by binding the framebuffer object, the renderbuffer, and the depth buffer, but I cannot figure out a means of copying from one framebuffer to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A framebuffer object is really just a meta-object which is a container for the surfaces it contains (either textures or renderbuffers). You will need to create the color/depth/stencil you need and "attach" them to the 
relevant attachment points in the framebuffer object.

In terms of copying from one surface to another, you either can use glBlitFramebuffer, or just render a 2D quad loading the offscreen surface as a texture and set up the texture coordinates so it is a 1:1 copy.

Note that "rendering over the top of what is already in memory" is relatively expensive on most mobile GPUs which are tilebased (they must read the old state into a GPU-local memory), especially if you then need a separate copy to blit the offscreen buffer into the on-screen one. I would suggest profiling to make sure that this scheme really is faster than just re-rendering, as it sounds like it may not be.

Comment: On the expense: Apple, at least, even supports the discard extension which explicitly permits render targets to pass into an undefined state because the cost of streaming the computed buffers back out to storage for reuse often isn't desirable. It's much more common to want to get to display and then throw away the intermediate data.

Comment: True - it's a standard part of OpenGL ES 3.0 so I guess everyone supports it now - but the OP explicitly stated he wanted to keep the old contents. Invalidating them before they were written out conflicts with the "desire to keep" requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately openGL ES 2.0 in android does not support blitting. Based on your suggestions I am going to try to use vertex buffer objects, since they may be more efficient than blitting, and since I could not get draw to texture to work earlier.

Comment: Blit = render two triangles, with texture size == screen size. How do you think all of the user interfaces and 2D games work in Android if they cannot write a texture to screen?

Vertex Buffer Objects are about sending geometry data, so not sure that is going to help anything here ...

Comment: @Isogen74: What he means to say is that `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` is not supported. That is true, the mechanism to directly copy pixels from one framebuffer to another was never implemented in OpenGL ES 2.0 (which makes renderbuffers _a lot_ less useful). But, fullscreen textured quads (triangle strip) can be used to do roughly the same thing. The only thing you miss out on without `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` is MSAA resolve, but that's probably not a big deal on ES 2.0 class mobile GPUs anyway.

Comment: @Isogen74 I thought it was relevant in supporting your point that what feels like it should be free is actually relatively expensive. So not something for the poster to use, just further exposition on why yours is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

For step 3, you use the texture you rendered to (the one that is used as the FBO color attachment), and sample from it while drawing a screen size quad. You can use very simple shaders for that. The vertex shader for the copy will look something like this:

```
#version 100
attribute vec2 Pos;
varying vec2 TexCoord;
void main() {
    TexCoord = 0.5 * Pos + 0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(Pos, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

and the fragment shader:

```
#version 100
uniform sampler2D Tex;
varying vec2 TexCoord;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Tex, TexCoord);
}
```

Then you draw a quad that covers the range [-1.0, 1.0] in both x and y.

There's another option. Unfortunately it's not portable, but will work on some devices. The following is copied from my own recent answer here: [Fast Screen Flicker while NOT drawing on Android OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925069/fast-screen-flicker-while-not-drawing-on-android-opengl/28928127#28928127).

For this approach, you call:

```
eglSurfaceAttrib(display, surface, EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR, EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED);
```

while setting up the context/surface. This requests that the buffer content is preserved after `eglSwapBuffers()`. It comes with a big caveat, though: This is not supported on all devices. You can test if it's supported with:

```
EGLint surfType = 0;
eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, &surfType);
if (surfType & EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED_BIT) {
    // supported!
}
```

You can also request this functionality as part of choosing the config. As part of the attributes passed to `eglChooseConfig()`, add:

```
...
EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT | EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED_BIT,
...
```

But again, this is **not supported** on all devices. So it's only really an option if you're targeting specific devices, or have a functional fallback if it's not supported.