# different behavior in Opengl ES android

Tags: android, opengl-es

.Renderer for performance reasons only drawing once the background, then I use the glscissors to draw  parts , this is the simplified code :

```
public class myGame extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {

    private boolean firstTime;

    public myGame(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        firstTime=true;
        this.setRenderer(this);
        this.setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
        gl.glOrthof(0, width, 0, height, 1, -1);
        //Select blue color 
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1f, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //only paint blue color then does nothing
        if(firstTime)
        {

            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            firstTime=false;
        }
        else
        {
            //other actions ..........
        }

    }

}
```

This code  works on my tablet( android 4) or on the emulator  , but i have problems with  Xperia Neo (2.3.3)  : first frame draw 1 blue   , second frame draw black, next blue , next black …..

Do I need to set some parameter ?  What I can do to fix this behavior?

Comment: try to draw the background twice instead of once, sounds silly but might work

Comment: sounds silly but it works! thanks !

Comment: np ^^, but i am not sure if this is a good solution and works on all devices, let the question open, maybe someone who knows whats going on has a better answer to this

Comment: thks , waiting for a better solution ....

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make this work reliably on all possible devices is to draw a complete frame on each redraw. This means that you either need to call `glClear()` at the start of each frame, or make sure that your rendering covers all pixels of the window.

As already suggested in a comment above, you *may* have better success if you clear the first 2 or 3 frames. But this relies on the system using double or triple buffering, which is not guaranteed at all. Also, it will not really work for incremental drawing, since in frame `n` you will still miss the rendering you added in frame `n - 1`. For example, if the system is using simple double buffering, the previous content for frame `n` would be the content of frame `n - 2`.

The EGL documentation specifies why the result is undefined. From the `eglSwapBuffers()` [man page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglSwapBuffers.xhtml):

> The contents of ancillary buffers are always undefined after calling eglSwapBuffers. The contents of the color buffer are left unchanged if the value of the EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR attribute of surface is EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED, and are undefined if the value is EGL_BUFFER_DESTROYED. The value of EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR can be set for some surfaces using eglSurfaceAttrib.

The last part of this suggests a possible solution, but it comes with a substantial caveat: It is not supported on all devices. More details about this aspect are in my answer here: [Fast Screen Flicker while NOT drawing on Android OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925069/fast-screen-flicker-while-not-drawing-on-android-opengl/28928127#28928127).

In reality, depending on the graphics architecture, it can actually be faster to call `glClear()` at the start of each frame even if it's not needed. Particularly when rendering to FBOs, the previous content of the render target has to be restored otherwise, and clearing it may be more efficient than restoring the previous content. ES 3.0 and later have a `glInvalidateFramebuffer()` call for these situations, which tells the implementation that the previous content does not have to be restored.

If rendering a full frame is really **very** expensive in your use case, and you can save a lot of time by rendering incrementally, the only portable option is that you render to an offscreen target (FBO), and then blit the content to the default framebuffer when a redraw is needed.